# Oracle Sequence Object Used in Multiple Schemas

Tags: oracle, schema, sequence

I need to use a same sequence object in multiple Oracle schemas (stored procs). Is it possible to achieve that by altering the sequence owner that all schemas are able to utilize the object?

## Update

As the first commenter indicated, all is needed to grant insert (or other) privileges to a certain user:

```
Grant insert on seq_name to user_name;
```

or

```
Grant all on seq_name to user_name;
```

Comment: You don't need to alter the owner, just grant `select` on that sequence to the other Oracle users.

Comment: You can't alter the owner anyway, except by dropping and re-creating it. As @a_horse says, you don't need to.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would you please put your answer below for credit?